# Get wrong characters jquery.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, encoding

I'm using with the file: `jquery.fileuploader.min`. when I change the string in the file from English text to Hebrew it returns wrong encoding.

I changed to:

```
 text:{uploadButton:"עיין",cancelButton:"Cancel",......
```

instead of:

```
text:{uploadButton:"Upload A File",cancelButton:"Cancel",......
```

Then I get in the Html button: "����" instead of "עיין".

I have in the body a meta tag of Enciding:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

So I don't know why it happens.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't save your file with the proper encoding ?

Comment: Typical encoding issue, use UTF8 without BOM encoding when saving text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) wrote, I opened the `jquery.fileuploader.min` sheet in Notepad and saved it to `utf-8` unicode instead of `ansi`